# How can I install jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation, jdk

I downloaded jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz from the Oracle website.

How can I install jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz?

I have tried `apt-get install jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz` and also

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Relevant: [How can I install Sun JDK on a Debian based system?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106940)

Answer (score 34):

look here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-oracles-java-as-the-default-java-in-ubuntu

not the accepted answer but Barracuda's, which I reproduce below:

> to set Oracle's Java SE Development Kit as the system default Java
>   just download the latest Java SE Development Kit from [here][1] then
>   create a directory somewhere you like in your file system for example
>   `/usr/java` now extract the files you just downloaded in that
>   directory:
>
> ```
> $ sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u5-linux-i586.tar.gz -C /usr/java
> ```
>
> now to set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:
>
> ```
> $ JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/
> $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000
> $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000
> ```
>
> make sure the Oracle's java is set as default java by:
>
> ```
> $ update-alternatives --config java
> ```
>
> you get something like this:
>
> ```
> There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
>
>   Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> * 0            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java                  20000     auto mode
>   1            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java                  20000     manual mode
>   2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
>
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
> ```
>
> pay attention to the asterisk before the numbers on the left and if
>   the correct one is not set choose the correct one by typing the number
>   of it and pressing enter. now test your java:
>
> ```
> $ java -version
> ```
>
> if you get something like the following, you are good to go:
>
> ```
> java version "1.8.0_05"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> also note that you might need root permission or be in sudoers group
>   to be able to do this. I've tested this solution on both ubuntu 12.04
>   and Debian wheezy and it works in both of them.
>
> [1]:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I have made the edit for you but next time, please do it yourself.

Comment: thanks Simone. i used: $ sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u5-linux-i586.tar.gz -C /usr/java

now to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable:

$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/java 20000
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac ${JAVA_HOME%*/}/bin/javac 20000

make sure the Oracle's java is set as default java by:

$ update-alternatives --config java
$ java -version

Comment: This worked for me. First check if directory `/usr/java` is present and if not use `mkdir /usr/java`. 
Thanks !!